# Accessing an hidden input field in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to get the value of an input field. I get undefined with the if condition on the hidden field. I have the same condition in  element which triggers the function. It works when i tried  it without *ngIf="fileLoadedFlag" in input element. I don`t understand what may be the problem ?

```
 <input type="hidden" *ngIf="fileLoadedFlag" [value]="pictureName" #hiddenPicAccessor />
 <span *ngIf="fileLoadedFlag" >{{pictureName}} </span>
<i *ngIf="fileLoadedFlag" (click)="removePicture(hiddenPicAccessor)" class="fa fa-times fa-2x" style="color:red" ></i>
```

And my test code

```
  removePicture(hiddenPicAccessor){
    alert(hiddenPicAccessor);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of individually setting *ngIfs, set a wrapper

```
<span *ngIf="fileLoadedFlag">
  <input type="text" [value]="pictureName" #hiddenPicAccessor />
  <span >{{pictureName}} </span>
  <button (click)="removePicture(hiddenPicAccessor.value)" style="color:red" >Click</button>
</span>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvydnp?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: yes but why can`t i access the hidden field, since they all have the same if condition ?

Comment: You mean why when you leave ngif on the the input tag, it's not defined? Because ngif will remove input from the dom and even though they all have ngif they are not 'tracked' at the same time

Comment: I removed the ngIf but still doesnt understand the problem. The hidden field is in the dom since the fileLoadedFlag is true. But it is undefined when clicked... @Vega

Comment: The point is when removed from the dom the # variable is no more accesible with the button which is added/hidden with the same. Have you added the wrapper as I answered or just removed from everywhere?

Comment: It's an expected behaviour. This may answer to your question: github.com/angular/angular/issues/6179

Comment: i will accept your answer, issue is still weird though :) @Vega